# Convert string to integer or default

Tags: c#, converting

I need my string-to-int converter to handle all exceptions without throwing any errors. I also have a use case where I need the default value to be less than zero if the `TryParse` is false.

- Is there a built-in way of doing this?
- Should I make any changes to the method?

```
public int ToInt32OrDefault(string value, int defaultValue = 0)
{
    int result;
    if (Int32.TryParse(value, out result) == false)
        result = defaultValue;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `int` rather than `Int32`
2. You can write an inline expression rather than a multi-line statement

I would prefer to write an extension method here to wrap this method:

```
public static class IntExtension
{
    public static int ToInt32OrDefault(this string value,int defaultValue=0)
    {
        int result;
        return int.TryParse(value, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the name `ToInt32OrDefault` was better ;-)

Comment: @paritosh It's not obvious to me why using 'int' is better than using 'Int32' especially if 'Int32' is retained in the function name. Is it a matter of style?

Comment: ["As a matter of style, use of the keyword is favored over use of the complete system type name."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664635.aspx)

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks for providing the link . it is more of style of writing code

Comment: In response to the style, I've been using the system type name for utility functions and the keyword for everything else. I like seeing the difference but maybe I'm the minority.

Comment: Is it common for extension methods to handle null? Would it make more sense to create it as a Utility method like `Convert.ToInt32` and `Int32.TryParse`?

Comment: With subsequent improvements in C#, we can shorten this syntactically even further as `=> int.TryParse(value, out var result) ? result : defaultValue;`.